# How to compare two TeX codes and mark differences with color

Tags: miktex, winedt, comparison, dvipdf

I would like to find easy tool, which compares two TeX codes and generates a PDF file of the first code, in which the differences from the second code are marked by a given color.
I use winedt 7.0 under windows 7.

I just noticed that latexdiff provides what I need. As far as I understand it is included in Miktex. Is there an interface (menu commands) in winedt 7.0, which allow to work with latexdiff ?

Comment: Why not `Notepad++` with the `compare` plugin?

Comment: You could write an `arara` rule which would be editor independent

Comment: Should this question be edited to reflect the new question? Maybe a follow-up question?

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, you are absolutely right. For the moment I use `latexdiff` command using console (cmd.exe). Note that one also need to install Perl to work with this command.

Comment: @cmhughes Could you please explain how to write an `arara` rule (for this case) ? Or please provide a link with good documentation.

Comment: On Linux, Meld is a good option.

Comment: If you show me an example of command-line you use to launch `latexdiff`, I will tell you how to have a button in WinEdt to do that.

Comment: @karlkoeller I use command `latexdiff old_file.tex revised_file.tex > output_file.tex`. So there are three options - two input files and one output file.

Comment: Does it work or you wanted something else?

Comment: @MarioS.E. as far as I know `Notepad++` has no `DVI Search` and `DVI Inverse Search` properties. So I prefer to work with `winedt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update (2016-04-10)

An add-on for running `latexdiff` from within WinEdt is available: [latexdiff](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/latexdiff.html).

If you want, you can revert the changes in MainMenu.ini and Toolbar.ini and install the add-on.

---

### Original answer

This is a simple way to have a button in WinEdt 7 (this one works in v7 only) to run `latexdiff`.

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Main Menu" item (`MainMenu.ini` gets opened)
3. Just before the line

   ```
     ITEM="Compile"
   ```

   add the following lines

   ```
     ITEM="LaTeXdiff"
       CAPTION="&LaTeXdiff"
       CONFIG_FILTER="Default;MiKTeX;TeX Live"
       IMAGE="CompareDocs"
       SAVE_INPUT=1
       MACRO=`WinExe('','cmd.exe /C latexdiff old_%n.tex %n.tex > new_%n.tex','%p','',011100);Open("new_%n.tex");`
       SHORTCUT="16452::Ctrl+D"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>
5. Now (in the "Options Interface") double-click the "Toolbar" item (`Toolbar.ini` gets opened)
6. Just before the line

   ```
     BUTTON="Compile"
   ```

   add the following line

   ```
     BUTTON="LaTeXdiff"
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

---

That's it. Now you have a toolbar button

[image]

a menu item in the "Accessories" menu

[image]

and a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) to run `latexdiff`.

---

### How to use it

Suppose you are working on a file `foo.tex`. Save the old version as `old_foo.tex`. Make the changes you need in `foo.tex` and make sure that `foo.tex` is the file in the main window.

At this point, choose one of the above methods to run `latexdiff`. A resulting file `new_foo.tex` will get opened.

Comment: For those who are interested, I found [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.winedt/7190) (see reply by James Melton | 8 May 2012 08:12) a more suitable and more interactive `MACRO`

Comment: Karl, Can you please add a line for using `accept` and / `decline` and `rcs/vcs..` versions too? How about making a macro for winedt.org? Sorry but I always find pleasure in troubling you ;-) BTW +1.

Comment: @Harish Busy with v8.1, so no chance for a contribution for winedt.org. About the first question, I don't understand.

Comment: Oh. sorry Karl. But you got a mail!

Answer (score 4):

For this purpose I use program [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) on windows.

You can load both file to be compared and each difference is marked. You can change in winmerge the code, copy from one file to the other and so on. Please see the shown screenshots on the web page http://winmerge.org/?lang=en.

From the homepage (follow the link above):

> WinMerge is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows.
>   WinMerge can compare both folders and files, presenting differences in
>   a visual text format that is easy to understand and handle.

Comment: I need to see the differences in the compiled dvi/PDF file.

Comment: [http://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff)
The `latexdiff` command takes two tex codes and generates a new tex code. Compiling this new tex code, one gets dvi/PDF file with the differences marked in red (for old version) and blue (for new version).

Answer (score 2):

After a few years of using TexMaker, I just realized it includes a comparison tool. To access it you must first enable the source viewer (red ellipse):

[image: Texmaker Spanish]

Then select the source file (yellow ellipse) to be compared to the one you are currently editing, and finally launch the tool by pressing the "<>" button (blue ellipse).